# Python: List of dictionaries. Count elements based on key of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-science

I read a csv file, using `DictReader`.

I have a list of dictionaries:

eg:

```
a = [{'Name':'A','Class':'1'},{'Name':'B','Class':'1'},{'Name':'C','Class':'2'}]
```

I want to count the number of entries in the list that have 'Class' == 1.

Is it possible to do it without a loop?

EDIT:

I have tried the following:

```
count = 0
for k in a:
    if k['Class'] == '1':
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions#sum) with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> xs = [{'Name':'A','Class':'1'},
          {'Name':'B','Class':'1'},
          {'Name':'C','Class':'2'}]
>>> sum(x.get('Class') == '1' for x in xs)
2
```

Comment: @DYZ Will return None when key is not present instead of raising error.

Comment: @MYGz, Using `dict.get` was on purpose to prevent the `KeyError`.

Comment: I know. DYZ was asking about it.

Comment: @MYGz NVM, I got it.

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension as well, to retrieve dictionaries matching your criteria then calculating its `len`:

```
>>> len([d for d in a if d.get('Class')=='1'])
2
```

EDIT: Timing Profile under Python3.5.2

```
>>>import timeit
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="len([d for d in a if d.get('Class')=='1'])", globals={'a':a})
0.8056499021768104
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="sum(x.get('Class') == '1' for x in a)", globals={'a':a})
0.9977147589670494
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="len(list(filter(lambda x: x.get('Class')=='1' , a)))", globals={'a':a})
1.3259506113099633
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
a = [{'Name':'A','Class':'1'},{'Name':'B','Class':'1'},{'Name':'C','Class':'2'}]
print(len(filter(lambda x: x.get('Class')=='1' , a)))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty the old fashion way to solve the problem, but if you want to do it in this way using the for loop, you can try this.

```
a = [{'Name':'A','Class':'1'},{'Name':'B','Class':'1'},{'Name':'C','Class':'2'}]

cnt = 0
for k in a:
    if k['Class'] == '1':
        cnt += 1
print(cnt)
```

output

```
2
```